# In a solar cell when an electron is freed due to light in the depletion layer, why does it move to N-type layer even though it is negatively charged?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electrons, atoms, solar-cells

Even though in a solar cell the N-type layer is negatively charged why do the electrons from the depletion layer get attracted to it?

Comment: Because of the field in the depletion layer.

Comment: @JonCuster What kind of field can you elaborate ?

Comment: The electric field that forms the depletion layer to bring the Fermi levels into alignment. This is pretty fundamental to the depletion layer and why it exists in the first place.

Comment: But then why doesn't the depletion layer keeps on expanding, ie. what prevents the electrons in the N-type layer to fuse with the positively charged ions present near the boundary of the depletion layer and N-type layer.

Comment: Because the carriers have been brought into equilibrium. If you apply a reverse potential you can expand the depletion region, a common technique for detectors where you want more signal. But you need to go look at diode theory from the beginning - too long to answer in a comment.

Comment: Ok, I read from several places and what I understood is that the N-type layer is not negatively charged but it contains Phosphorus which is pentavalent and because silicon forms a covalent bond with 4 electrons the 5th one is set free. In the P-type layer, there are trivalent boron atoms and that's why a hole is created even though there is no charge imbalance.

Comment: In the depletion region, the free electrons from the N-type layer fill up the holes in the P-type layer and that's why near the N-type and depletion region boundary a positive charge is formed and in the P-type and depletion region boundary, a negative charge is formed. Now when the light strikes and knocks off an electron from the depletion region the electron gets attracted to the N-type layer because the boundary is positively charged and the hole gets collected in the P-type layer because there the boundary is negatively charged. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main misunderstanding is that the n-layer is neutrally charged overall so it does not attract anything.

Only in the depletion region is there an electric field. The electric fields acts to sweep electrons towards the n-layer and holes toward the p-layer.

The depletion region partially overlaps both n and p doped layers. The part in the n-side is positively charged because the region is *depleted* of electrons which were once bound to the n-type dopants. This makes the n-side of the depletion region positive which attracts electrons towards the n-layer.